# Kramers degeneracy in a nontrivial model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, group-theory, time-reversal-symmetry

In many textbooks, [Kramers' degeneracy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%27_theorem) is presented as a nontrivial consequence of the time reversal symmetry of a system with an odd number of electrons.

The problem is, for such systems, the double degeneracy of each level is quite natural and expected. You have an odd number of electrons, so the total angular momentum $J$ is half-integer, and you have time reversal symmetry which means you have no magnetic field, hence $|J,M\rangle $ and $|J ,-M \rangle $ must be degenerate. Note that $M\neq 0 $ because $J$ is a half-integer.

This is most clear if you have a single electron and no magnetic field. The up state must be degenerate with the down state.

Could anyone give a nontrivial example of Kramers degeneracy? For which we have to invoke the highbrow  time-reversal symmetry etc?